# How to get first letter of each line in python?

Tags: python

here is what I got txt and open
txt file looks like

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
```

the show['Cat\n','Dog\n','Cat\n','Dog\n'........]

**output**
But I would like to get this

> ['C\n','D\n','C\n','D\n'........]

Comment: Try using `f.readlines()`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files.

Comment: Break this down into smaller parts. For example, you need to figure out how to get the lines of a file one at a time. Then you need to figure out how to get the first letter from each of those lines. Finally, you need to figure out how to print it in the format you want. Solve each part separately and then you'll have a working program.

Answer (score 3):

First you'll want to open the file in read mode (`r` flag in `open`), then you can iterate through the file object with a for loop to read each line one at a time. Lastly, you want to access the first element of each line at index 0 to get the first letter.

```
first_letters = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        first_letters.append(line[0])

print(first_letters)
```

If you want to have the newline character still present in the string you can modify line 5 from above to:

```
first_letters.append(line[0] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    f = open("data.txt", "r")
    
    for x in f:
      print(x[0]) 

    f.close()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?